# How can i move these list items and label to be next to the image

Tags: html, css

I need to get the list items (Home, Last Mile, Supply Chain....etc) as well as the Project management label next to the image(grey area). I feel like this should be very simple. But I cant figure it out for the life of me.

[image]

here is the html code I have:

```
        <div class="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
            <asp:image runat="server" CssClass="logo" ImageUrl="~/FidelitoneLogo.png" Width="62px" Height="33px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="Menu">
        <ul>  
            <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Last Mile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Order Fulfillment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Supply Chain</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">QB Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shared Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Employee Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Quality</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblProjectManagement" runat="server" Text="Project Management" CssClass="pmLabel" Width="139px" Height="35px"></asp:Label>
        </div>
```

and the CSS

```
.logo {
background: no-repeat;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
width: 65px;
}

.Menu ul {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

.Menu ul li {
display: inline;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 8px;
}

.Menu ul li a {
vertical-align: top;
padding-bottom:
}

.navbar div {
display: inline;
}

.pmLabel {
display: block;
font-size: 14px;
padding-left: 5px;
vertical-align: top;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left;` to your `.logo` class

https://jsfiddle.net/1wnyrfy6/

Answer (score 0):

You need to float everything left. Try adding this code:

```
.logo {
    float: left;
}
```

I hope that helps. The other elements -- list and label should float up and to the right of the logo.